# R Shiny, apply an implemented function on a data taken as input

Tags: r, dataframe, input, shiny

I would like to implement an App which takes a .csv file as input (the user selects the file from his computer), then I want to take this file as a parameter in a function "f" that I've implemented previously.

I can give you the ui.R and server.R

**ui.R**

```r
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file",
                "Put your portfolio data here",
                accept=c(".csv")
                )
    ),

    mainPanel(tableOutput("table"))
  )

))
```

**server.R**

```r
library(shiny)



shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    data <- reactive({
      file1 <- input$file
      if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
      read.csv2(file=file1$datapath)
    })


    #to view the data    
    output$table <- renderTable({
      if(is.null(data())){return ()}
      data()
    })

})
```

Finally my function "f" is supposed to give a .csv file as output.

Comment: you have to add a `downloadButton` widget in the sidebar penel in order to download the data as a csv. https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.4/downloadButton.html

Answer (score 0):

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file",
                "Put your portfolio data here",
                accept=c(".csv")
                ),
      downloadButton(download_data.csv, "Download File")
    ),

    mainPanel(tableOutput("table"))
  )

))
```

**server.R**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    data <- reactive({
      file1 <- input$file
      if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
      read.csv2(file=file1$datapath)
    })


    #to view the data    
    output$table <- renderTable({
      if(is.null(data())){return ()}
      data()
    })

    # to download the tadata
    output$download_data.csv <- downloadHandler(

    filename = "download_data.csv",
    content = function(file){

      data <- data() # At this point you should have done the transformation 
                     # to the data

      write.csv(data, file, row.names = F)

    }

  )


})
```